# Error 500 while deploying JCo project to SCP

Tags: java, jco, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to connect a RFC to a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. The project would be deployed to SCP and I  added a destination on SCP like this:

[image: Destination]

The project contains a Servlet which executes the below code and those two combined work just fine.

```java
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
  
    PrintWriter responseWriter = response.getWriter();       
   
    try
    {   
  JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("jcodemo");  
        JCoRepository repo = destination.getRepository();
        JCoFunction rfcConnection = repo.getFunction("ZRFM_GET_EQUIPMENTS");
        rfcConnection.execute(destination);
  
      responseWriter.println("<html><head>");                   
      responseWriter.println("</head><body>");
  responseWriter.println("<p>Test</p>");
        responseWriter.println("</body></html>");
  
    }

}
```

I want to alter the destination at runtime (to let users use their own account), so I added a `DestinationDataProvider`. It is used in multiple guides who make custom destinations. (I left it empty to save some space, its functionality doesn't matter here.)

```java
    public class DestProvider implements DestinationDataProvider {

    @Override
    public Properties getDestinationProperties(String arg0) throws DataProviderException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDestinationDataEventListener(DestinationDataEventListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsEvents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    
    }
```

In order for Eclipse to recognize the import `com.sap.conn.jco.ext.DestinationDataProvider`, I added the **SAPJCo3.jar** as a reference to the project. I didn't need the import before this part.

[image: Reference]

I added this piece of code to my Servlet to instantiate one. The second I reference this in the Servlet, the webpage returns a `500` error.

```java
    DestProvider d = new DestProvider();
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but I keep getting an error. The logs of the Java application are empty as well, so I do not have any idea on how to continue with this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot register your own DestinationDataProvider on the SAP Cloud Platform.
`sapjco3.jar` is the standalone SAP Java Connector and is not suitable to be used/deployed on the SCP. This platform already comes with all the necessary artifacts including a special JCo client version. The RFC connectivity to on-premise SAP systems is achieved via a TLS tunnel to the SAP Cloud Connector.

Maybe this tutorial helps with understanding the architecture and how to use JCo RFCs on the SAP Cloud Platform:
https://www.sap.com/germany/developer/tutorials/hcp-scc-onpremise-extension-jco-rfc.html

For custom JCo destinations you should be able to use the class [JCoCustomDestination](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/index.html?com/sap/conn/jco/JCoCustomDestination.html) which will allow to switch user logon credentials, but not to change the logon parameters which define the target SAP system.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your clear explanation.